# What is the use of Website preference in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, browser

in Website preference, if I select Mobile version instead of Desktop version. what is the use of it. is it redirect automatically to mobile version of current site or is it some thing relate to browser performance?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many websites today offer a slimmed-down version of their full desktop site that's customized for the smaller screens and slower Internet connections commonly found on mobile phones. Some people prefer these mobile sites, others don't. Internet Explorer Mobile can help show you the version you prefer.

Grabbed from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/howto/wp7/web/changing-privacy-and-other-browser-settings.aspx).

You might also find [this](http://www.google.com) handy.

Comment: slimmed-down version means, for example bing.com is desktop and this http://m.bing.com/ is slimmed-down version?

Comment: Bingo! You'll tend to find that the mobile sites won't have much in the way of graphics. The mobile site can be implemented in a variety of ways, it's generally css or a seperate server. AFAIK